# Wsdl for a REST service issues

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm trying to use the GetPostCodeDetailsByPlaceName method from [this](http://www.restfulwebservices.net/rest/USAZipCodeService.svc?wsdl) wsdl. I can't figure out how the parameters should go. Am I looking at this the wrong way or is it incomplete?

I've tried guessing a ton of things like:
[This](http://www.restfulwebservices.net/ServiceContracts/Rest/2008/01/IPostalCodeService/GetPostCodeDetailsByPlaceName?placeName=SD) and 
[this](http://www.restfulwebservices.net/ServiceContracts/Rest/2008/01/IPostalCodeService/GetPostCodeDetailsByPlaceName?PlaceName=SD)

even
[this](http://www.restfulwebservices.net/ServiceContracts/Rest/2008/01/IPostalCodeService/GetPostCodeDetailsByPlaceName?parameters=SD)

Anyone make any sense of it? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it's a REST service?

Comment: See my comment to @Surge below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this web service has a WSDL, it is a SOAP based web service, not a RESTful web service. You can use [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) to generate a WS client based on the WSDL, or you can use a tool like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to invoke the web service.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing since it is wsdl, but if you go to http://www.restfulwebservices.net/Service.aspx?ID=23 the author seems to think it models a RESTful service thus my confusion. Was wondering if was missing something or there is an issue on their end?

Comment: Yes, there's an issue. Apparently, they have SOAP web services in addition to REST.

Comment: The domain name restfulwebservices.net is quite ironic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

WSDL = SOAP
WADL = REST

Hence the thread title itself is invalid!!!